# Character keeps changing even though I don't change it

Tags: arrays, arduino, char

I have an Arduino app in which I am creating multiple character arrays.  I create one and it prints out in the monitor as the array I want.  I then create another character array using an entirely different set of variables.  The second character array is what I want but when I print out the first character array in the monitor it has the value of the second character array.

Here is the code:

//TEMP is stored in EEPROM and I retrieve it like this

```
String vvvv;
for(int i=0;i<33;i++)
{vvvv =  vvvv + char(EEPROM.read(0x90+i));
} 
int firstCommaIndexa = vvvv.indexOf(',');
String wstemp = vvvv.substring(0, firstCommaIndexa);
TEMP = wstemp;
```

//I then use this code to create my first char

```
char tripchar[] = "";
String tripUserString =String(TEMP) + String("/feeds/trip,aaa");
int tripCommaIndexb = tripUserString.indexOf(",");
String tripSt = tripUserString.substring(0,tripCommaIndexb);
int tripleng = tripCommaIndexb;
Serial.println("tripleng");
Serial.print(tripleng);
tripSt.toCharArray(tripchar,tripleng+1);
Serial.println("trip1");
Serial.print(tripSt);       //this print out as XXXX/feeds/trip
Serial.println("tripchar1");
Serial.print(tripchar);     //this prints out as XXXX/feeds/trip
```

// Then I create my second char with this code.

```
char userbattery2[] = "";
String UserString =String(TEMP) + String("/feeds/wifi-connection,aaa");
int firstCommaIndexb = UserString.indexOf(",");
String batterySt = UserString.substring(0,firstCommaIndexb);
int leng = firstCommaIndexb;
Serial.println("leng");
Serial.print(leng);
batterySt.toCharArray(userbattery2,leng+1);
Serial.println("battery");
Serial.print(batterySt);        //this prints as XXXX/feeds/wifi-connection
Serial.print(userbattery2);     //this prints as XXXX/feeds/wifi-connection
Serial.println("trip2");
Serial.print(tripSt);           //this prints as XXXX/feeds/trip
Serial.println("tripchar2");
Serial.print(tripchar);         //but this prints out as XXX/feeds/wifi-connection
```

I have tried various solutions but to no avail.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and why this doesn't work and also SHOW me what I need to do to make this work so the Character arrays don't change but always stay the same after I set them.

Comment: The size of  array `char userbattery2[]="";` is 1 (try printout sizeof(userbattery2) to see it). so when you trying to copy something into the array with `batterSt.toCharArray(userbatter2, leng+1)`, the array is overflowed. If you want to hold a substring of `leng` long, you need to declare it as `char userbatter2[leng+1]{'\0'}` (create the an array of leng and initialised it with '\0').

Comment: Where to put this.  If I put it in place of `char userbattery2[]="";` I get an error `leng not declare in scope`. If after `int leng = firstCommaIndexb` I get error `variable-sized object 'userbattery2' may not be initialized`.  So where should I put it.  Also userbattery2 isn't a problem it is `tripchar`that comes back different.  First it's `XXXX/feeds/trip` but after `userbattery2` it is `XXX/feeds/wifi-connection`.  First letter is gone but why does it change to the same as userbattery2 instead of staying `XXXX/feeds/trip`. `XXXX/feeds/wi` is really `XXXX/feeds/wifi-connection` miscopied.

Comment: Maybe you should pause and read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/arduino/arduino_arrays.htm) to understand how array works. How about move the `char userbattery2[leng+1]{'\0'}` after you get the value of `leng`?

Comment: You have the same problem with `char tripchar[] = "";` too. If you are saying `userbattery2` "isn't the problem", you don't understand the problem yet.

Comment: You are correct.  I read the post about integer arrays and one on char arrays and gleamed a little more understanding.  However I didn't see anything with {'/0'} on it.  I tried putting `char userbattery2[leng+1]{'/0'}` after `int leng = firstCommaIndexb;` but I got the following error.  `variable-sized object 'userbattery2' may not be initialized`.  I really do not understand the problem.  Could you help me do so?

Comment: I have tried putting `char userbattery2[leng+1] = '/0';` after I got the value of leng both for `userbattery2` and for `tripget2`.  But it doesn't help.  After I create `tripget2` which is `XXXX/feeds/trip` `userbattery2` changes from `XXXX/feeds/wifi-connection` to `XXXXX/feeds/trip`.  Is this what you wanted me to do.  `char userbattery2[leng+1]= '/0';` is supposed to say a terminator is necessary.  Is there something else I could try.  You are correct that I don't understand why one variable userbattery2 should effect the other triplet2.  Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Figured out and will post solution. Thank you for your suggestions and help.  I did a lot of reading and have come to a better understanding of arrays.  You were right that by allocating no memory for the arrays and then writing them the only character left was the first one and the rest were overwritten by the next array.  I tried your suggestion but it didn't seem to work.  Sorry I also was using a / instead of a \.  My final suggestion was to allocate way more memory that would be used since my longest array was 23 characters and I hope no-one creates a username longer than 27 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I only have to change a couple things to make this work.

//This part I left the same.
//TEMP is stored in EEPROM and I retrieve it like this

```
String vvvv;
for(int i=0;i<33;i++)
{vvvv =  vvvv + char(EEPROM.read(0x90+i));
} 
int firstCommaIndexa = vvvv.indexOf(',');
String wstemp = vvvv.substring(0, firstCommaIndexa);
TEMP = wstemp;
```

//I then use this code to create my first char
//Here I just changed the first line so it is assigned 50 characters of memory.  My longest array is 23 characters plus a username and I will make sure no-one creates a username of more than 26 characters.  I also moved this from void setup() to the space above making it global.

```
char tripchar[50] = "";
```

//this is in void setup()

```
String tripUserString =String(TEMP) + String("/feeds/trip,aaa");
int tripCommaIndexb = tripUserString.indexOf(",");
String tripSt = tripUserString.substring(0,tripCommaIndexb);
int tripleng = tripCommaIndexb;
Serial.println("tripleng");
Serial.print(tripleng);
tripSt.toCharArray(tripchar,tripleng+1);
Serial.println("trip1");
Serial.print(tripSt);       //this print out as XXXX/feeds/trip
Serial.println("tripchar1");
Serial.print(tripchar);     //this prints out as XXXX/feeds/trip
```

// Then I create my second char with this code.

```
char userbattery2[50] = ""; //this is also made global with a memory of 50

String UserString =String(TEMP) + String("/feeds/wifi-connection,aaa");
int firstCommaIndexb = UserString.indexOf(",");
String batterySt = UserString.substring(0,firstCommaIndexb);
int leng = firstCommaIndexb;
Serial.println("leng");
Serial.print(leng);
batterySt.toCharArray(userbattery2,leng+1);
Serial.println("battery");
Serial.print(batterySt);        //this prints as XXXX/feeds/wifi-connection
Serial.print(userbattery2);     //this prints as XXXX/feeds/wifi-connection
Serial.println("trip2");
Serial.print(tripSt);           //this prints as XXXX/feeds/trip
Serial.println("tripchar2");
Serial.print(tripchar);         //this now prints as XXXX/feeds/wifi-connection
```

I can now subscribe and publish to my MQTT broker.

I hope this helps anyone who has a problem with this.  I wish I could have initialized the char arrays with variable memory but I couldn't find a way.  If some knows of one let me know.